# SmartDEN Watchdpg without Internet access over Linux PC with IP forward

Tags: linux, ip, iptables, forwarding

I explain the assumption:

I have a local network, in which the router functions is done by an industrial Linux PC connected to the internet and a VPN; these are the PC data:

```
# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:60:e0:88:82:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:60:e0:88:82:44 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.2.55.1/24 brd 10.2.55.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.131/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 42358sec preferred_lft 42358sec
    inet6 fdd9:cbf6:173c::5e4/128 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdd9:cbf6:173c:0:260:e0ff:fe88:8244/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::260:e0ff:fe88:8244/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.2.0.44/16 brd 10.2.255.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::3c21:dab6:295d:15a9/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:95:01:f1:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The local address we use on the PC both to connect to it via the VPN and to connect to the local network is `10.2.55.1` (`br0`).

On the network, I have an Ippower (SmartDEN IP-Watchdog), to restart computers according to circumstances. Their address is `10.2.55.11`.

the ping between both is correct, and in its configuration, by not pinging the `ippower` with the PC, it is restarted.

I want to do the same with a `switch` connected directly to the `ippower`, with the rule that, if there is no internet (ping to `8.8.8.8` or `1.1.1.1`), restart the router; but the `ippower` has no internet outlet, while the PC does. When I try the ping to `8.8.8.8` in the web service's `ippower`, I get:

```
Ping/HTTP Test Result to 8.8.8.8: Timed out
```

When I ping through the interfaces, I get that I only ping through `br0`:

```
# ping -I enp1s0 8.8.8.8
ping: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than: enp1s0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.100.1 enp1s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 10218ms


# ping -I br0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.0.131 br0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=7.02 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=6.60 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=6.60 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.597/6.740/7.024/0.200 ms


# ping -I tun0 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.2.0.44 tun0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2026ms
```

What `iptables` rules would be appropriate for the forwarded networked element to have internet output? is there another better way to do it?

Comment: Hi, can you please add the results on these commands? On PC: `iptables -L`, `iptables -t nat -L`, `ip r`. Can you see the routing table on IPpower? And on your gateway? (192.168.0.1 or .254 i guess)

Comment: So your linux pc operates as the router, and if it does not connect to the internet, you would like the switch rebooted by a separate device?  why not have it ping the internet, and if that stops, notify the ipower?